# NestJS dynamic module registration

Tags: nestjs

I have a question regarding dynamic modules importing.
Let's say I have `@Injectable` service which depends on the parameter that came from the configuration:

```
@Injectable()
export class StatsService {
    constructor(@Inject(SERVICE_NAME) private serviceName: string) {}

    ...
}
```

Let's say I expose this service through the Dynamic module:

```
@Module({})
export class CoreServicesModule {
    static register(coreConfig: CoreServicesConfig): DynamicModule {
        const { serviceName } = coreConfig;
        return {
            module: CoreServicesModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: SERVICE_NAME,
                    useValue: serviceName
                },
                StatsService
            ],
            exports: [
                StatsService
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Let's say my application is pretty big, and I have a lot of different modules.
But I need `StatsService` in every one of them.

So for example to be able to use `StatsService` in one of the modules i need to do something like:

```
@Module({
    imports: [CoreServicesModule.register({ serviceName: 'test', ... })]
})
export class SomeModule { ... }
```

And I need to do it for each module...
Do we have a way to do it only once in NestJS?

Or how we can re-use the already registered module?

`@Global` decorator also not help me here cause I still need to import the module in each place...

Answer (score 0):

`@Global()` decorator will help you if you are interested in using `StatService` in all other modules without the need to import that module!

BUT from your code it seems that each module that import `CoreServicesModule` would also make a small adjustment to it by dynamically specifying the providers it has (such as `ValidationPipe`).
in that case you should NOT make it `@Global()` since global modules should be registered only once